# grpc c++ helloworld example doesn't compile

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

Getting compilation error in making helloworld example in grpc (ver 1.28.1) c++

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld -B/home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build/CMakeFiles /home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -s -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/greeter_async_server.dir/greeter_async_server.cc.o
In file included from /home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build/helloworld.grpc.pb.h:22:0,
                 from /home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc:30:
/home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build/helloworld.pb.h:73:35: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
 class HelloRequest PROTOBUF_FINAL :
                                   ^
/home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build/helloworld.pb.h:383:30: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
/home/test/Desktop/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build/helloworld.pb.h:383:30: error: expected declaration before end of line
CMakeFiles/greeter_async_server.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/greeter_async_server.dir/greeter_async_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/greeter_async_server.dir/greeter_async_server.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/greeter_async_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/greeter_async_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:103: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is after I cloned [gRPC repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc), [built it](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#clone-the-repository-including-submodules) on Ubuntu 16.04 using gcc ver 5.4.0 , and [built third party depenendencies](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/distrib/cpp/run_distrib_test_cmake.sh) (successful upto line 73 : building and installing grpc)